# How to implement the string SCAudioStream? - Sound Cloud

Tags: objective-c, audio, cloud, audio-streaming

I'm working with the sound cloud sdk, I'm trying to use their libraries to play Audio Stream.

I have not been able to find any reference on how to use that class.

I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [this libraries](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper) I can help you.

First of all you should run this method to get some info about track by its ID:

```
[api performMethod: @"GET" 
            onResource: @"tracks" 
        withParameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:trackID forKey:@"ids"] 
               context: @"trackid" 
              userInfo: nil];
```

If you don't know trackID and have only link to track like this : http://soundcloud.com/go-yoshimura/mikasasukasa, then run this method:

```
[api performMethod: @"GET" 
            onResource: @"resolve" 
        withParameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:songLink forKey:@"url"]
               context: @"songname" 
              userInfo: nil];
```

Then you should implement delegate's methods:

```
- (void)soundCloudAPI:(SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPI 
    didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data 
              context:(id)context 
             userInfo:(id)userInfo;

- (void)soundCloudAPI:(SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPI 
     didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
              context:(id)context 
             userInfo:(id)userInfo;
```

In first method you should parse data using JSON Parser (JSONKit or SBJSON). You should get NSDictionary.

```
streamURL = [(NSDictionary *)jsonData objectForKey:@"stream_url"];
streamable = [[(NSDictionary *)jsonData objectForKey:@"streamable"] boolValue];
```

If this track is streamable, you can get SCAudioStream this way:

```
stream = [[SCAudioStream alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:streamURL] authentication:auth];
```

Auth you can create earlier in your init method this way:

```
conf = [SCSoundCloudAPIConfiguration configurationForProductionWithClientID: kSCClientID
                                                                       clientSecret: kSCClientSecret
                                                                        redirectURL: kSCRedirectURL];
auth = [[SCSoundCloudAPIAuthentication alloc] initWithAuthenticationDelegate:self apiConfiguration:conf];
```

And now you have SCAudioStream.

```
//Playing
[stream play];

//Pause
[srteam pause];

//Seeking
[stream seekToMillisecond:ms startPlaying:YES];
```

That's all :)